# Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f'(0)=0$. Define $g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $f'(0)=0$. Define $g(x,y)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. Is $g$ differentiable on $\mathbb R^2$? Any hints on how to do it? I know definition of differentiability on $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

*One approach*

Have you calculated the partial derivatives and are they continuous about $(0,0)$? If so, then the function is differentiable.

*Another*

If you don't have that result yet, the partial derivatives will give you a sense of what $Df_{(0,0)}$ would be and you can confirm it with the formal definition of the limit.

Comment: Are you sure that existence of the partial derivatives implies existence of the total derivative?

Comment: If they exist in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and are continuous, yes

Comment: Ah "about" is the essential word here :)

Comment: Yes, that was a bit loose, you're right.

Comment: Thanks :) I like yours as well. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$g$ has the form $g(x) = f(\|x\|_2)$ where $x\in\mathbb R^2$. You should know that $x\mapsto \|x\|_2$ is a $C^\infty$ function, thus $g$ has the same differentiability properties as $f$.